# change css button border width without changing other effects

Tags: css

```html
<button>Foo</button>
<button style="border-width: 3px">Bar</button>
```

On Firefox these render as

[image]

Changing `border-width` has changed other effects. I just want to make the border smaller.

Here is the box model for the button on the left

[image]

I want the button to fit more tightly around the text something like this

[image]

According to the box model, it looks like the border is the only thing responsible for the vertical "padding".

How can I shrink the button to the text, preserving the aesthetic styles?

Comment: can you explain how the accepted answer preserve the asethetic styles? if you don't want to preserve *the default style* you should make it clear in the question because in this case it's trivial to remove the default style and apply a new one to all the buttons

Comment: I've since read elsewhere that applying any visual style (e.g. background-color) will trash the browser visual styles, but the accepted answer is pretty close and less hacky than yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
button {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<button>Foo</button>
<button style="border-width: 2px">Bar</button>
```